# Best-case Running-time to solve an NP-Complete problem

Tags: computational-complexity, computer-science, np

What is the fastest algorithm that exists to solve a particular NP-Complete problem? For example, a naive implementation of [travelling salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) is $O(n!)$, but with dynamic programming it can be done in $O(n^2 2^n)$. Is there any "easier" NP-Complete problem that has a better running time?

Note that I'm curious about exact solutions, not approximations.

Comment: There are a lot of NP-complete problems which are linear-time (or $n \log n$ time) reducible to 3-SAT (and vice versa). If one of these can be solved in $2^{O(n^\alpha)}$ time for $\alpha < 1$, they all can be. Most computer scientists think this is unlikely.


Comment: If it is travelling salesman problem,that graph can be decomposed small known graph which computer have already calculated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If P is an NP-complete problem, then define P<sub>k</sub> = instances of P in which the instances have been blown up from size n to size n<sup>k</sup> by padding them with blanks. Then P<sub>k</sub> is also NP-complete, but if P takes time exp(p(n)) to solve where p is some polynomial then P<sub>k</sub> can be solved in time essentially exp(p(n<sup>1/k</sup>)) (there's a little more time required to check that the input really does have the right amount of padding but unless the running time is polynomial this is a negligable fraction of the total time). So there is no "easiest" problem: for every problem you name this construction gives another easier but still NP-complete problem.

As for non-artificial problems: most hard graph problems like Hamiltonian circuit, that are hard when restricted to planar graphs, can be solved in time exponential in √n or in (√n)(log n) by dynamic programming using a recursive partition by graph separators.

Comment: Let me just add that the reparametrization phenomenon in the first paragraph is unavoidable even for "natural" problems.  For example, the question itself asserts that travelling salesman is $O(n!)$ in the naive algorithm.  However, if we simplify traveling salesman to the directed Hamiltonian path problem, then rigorously, as a function of the input length, the naive algorithm is actually $O(\sqrt{n}!)$ time.


Answer (score 0):

If P = NP, then there is a polynomial-time algorithm for solving any given NP-Complete problem.  Otherwise, it's known that there exist no general algorithms for any NP-Complete problem that are better than half-exponential: that is, f(x) where f(f(x)) is exponential.

Comment: Where is this result proved? It seems very surprising to me. Is what you're saying that the optimal algorithm for SAT might take   $O(n^5)$  time, it might take $O(2^{\sqrt{n}})$  time, but it cannot possibly take $O(n^{\log \log n})$ time? Or am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: I was thinking of Wigderson's result that a proof that DISCRETE-LOG can be solved in $O(f(x))$ time can be transformed into a proof that it can be solved in $O(\exp(f^{-1}(x))$. But this applies only to natural proofs in the sense of  Razborov-Rudich, so I was wrong my claim.

Comment: Thanks. That result sounds interesting ... I'm going to have to look at it.

Comment: It's cited in the Razborov-Rudich paper, I believe.  I don't know if it's been published apart from that.